# Copy Odata source to Azure Blob using ADF error

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy for an Odata source(Microsoft Dynamics Marketing) to Azure Blob storage using ADF and I get the below error. Anyone seen the below before?

Copy activity met an internal service error. For more information, provide this message to customer support. ErrorCode: 8005 ErrorCode=SystemErrorRefreshTokenInternalError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=There is an internal error to refresh token.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.CredentialService.DataContracts.ExceptionHandling.ServiceFaultException,Message=Exception of type 'Microsoft.DataTransfer.CredentialService.DataContracts.ExceptionHandling.ServiceFaultException' was thrown.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.CredentialService.ClientLibrary,'

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is caused by the AAD token is expired or revoked. To fix this, try to redo authorization for the impacted linked service and re deploy in ADF portal. See more details on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector/#token-expiration.